# SSRS Page break issue, with multiple table in each page

Tags: reporting-services, paging

I want to create a SSRS report. I have 5 tables that I want all of them to stay in one page, except when year changes, like below:

```
page1: year 2014
  table1
  table2
  table3
  table4
  table4

page2: year 2015 (the same tables as page 1, but with data for year 2)
  table1
  table2
  table3
  table4
  table5
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Create two subreports and place first subreport above the second one, for the first use data for 2014 and put an empty rectangle with page break at the very end. In the second subreport use 2015 data. The page break will place the second subreport in a new page. Let me know if you get stuck, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thank you Alejandro for your post

Comment: the problem is that years are not just 2014 and 2015. it could be just this two or more, base on how far back the data in data base can be found.

Comment: so we may have 3 or 2 or 5 years.

Comment: Maybe you can use `union` operator for each year at t-sql level, then add page break for each instance of year. Add to your question the five tables.

Comment: Actually the tables don't have the same fields, That is why I have to have 5 different tables. there fore using union is not an option for me. I am not sure though if I get exactly what you meant. did you mean to combine all five tables in 1 table?

Comment: I mean `union` table 1 from 2014 and table 1 from 2015 to get one table 1 for two years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (rather ugly) way to do this is to use a list filtered on Year.  Unfortunately this does mean that you need to return ALL your data in a single dataset.

What I have done previously, is create a table variable to return all the data in such as `@ReturnData`.  This has every field from every table you wish to return, as well as a `tableID` identifier.

I then insert all the tables into this @ReturnData table with the TableID set for the current insert statement, such as

```
INSERT INTO @ReturnData(tableID, col01, col02, col03)
SELECT
    1 AS tableID,
    a.col1 as col01,
    a.col2 as col02,
    a.col3 as col03,
   ...
FROM myTableA a
```

Then for the second table

```
INSERT INTO @ReturnData(tableID, col11, col12, col13)
SELECT
    2 AS tableID,
    b.col1 as col11,
    b.col2 as col12,
    b.col3 as col13,
FROM myTableB b
```

Then in Reporting Services you can create a list based on the grouped together returned dataset.  This list can be grouped on year, and each table can be filtered on the `tableID` column.

[image]

Note if there are common columns between the tables there is no reason, not to put data in a single column for both tables, as each row will have its own tableID identifier.

Comment: Thank you very much Jonnus, I try this.

Comment: Let me know how you get on and if you need further help